Is it possible to configure Entity Framework Core 8 with fluent API to create records in N:N table without an entity class as related entity?
Perhaps the title is a bit confused, but I will explain it.
I have a Movie and a Genre class and I would like to add record in a N:N table in the database because it is a many to many relationship.
This is my Movie class:
public sealed class Movie
{
    // Necesario para Entity Framework Core
    private Movie() { }

    public long Id { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    // other properties

    private List<long> _genresId = [];

    /// <summary>
    /// Los actores que trabajan en la película.
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyCollection<long> GenresId => _genresId;

    public void SetTitle(string paramTitle)
    {
        Title = paramTitle;
    }

    public void AddGenre(long paramGenre)
    {
        _generosIds.Add(paramGenre);
    }

    public void AddGenres(IEnumerable<long> paramGenres)
    {
        _genresId.AddRange(paramGenres);
    }
}

The Genre class:
public sealed class Genre
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public long Name { get; private set; }
}

This the the configuration in fluent API:
paramConfiguracionMovie
        .HasMany<Genre>()
        .WithMany()
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "GenresOfMovies",
            j => j
                .HasOne<Genero>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("GenreId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
            j => j
                .HasOne<Pelicula>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("MovieId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey("MovieId", "GenreId");
            });

This is how I am trying to set the relation between the movie and the genre:
List<long> genresIds = [];
genresIds.Add(1);
genresIds.Add(2);
genresIds.Add(3);

Pelicula movie = new Pelicula();

movie.AddGenres(genresIds);

_context.Movies.Add(movie);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

The problem is that the records are not created in the N:N table GenresOfMovies in the database.
I guess the problem is in the configuration in the fluent API, but I don't know how it doesn't work.
What I would like to avoid it is to have a list of Genre instead of a list of long, because to create the relationship I don't need the whole genre, only the ID, but I don't know if it is possible this.
If I would have list of Genre, I know how to do it, but I would like to avoid to create the objects of Genre only with the ID, because from the client I get only the a list of IDs.
In summary, is it possible in Entity Framework Core 8 to create the N:N records when I only have a list of long?
Thanks.
